# Django оптимизация xhr запросов

Tags: mysql, django, производительность, fetch, xhr

Мужики я долго пытался ускорить то, что я написал не получилось .-. . Обычное Django приложение для работы небольшого предприятия, появилось необходимость создания накладных для сбора товаров. Вкратце есть у нас в модель документа накладной и строчек записей в эту накладную, в другом модуле программы есть модель с каталогом всех товаров, на странице с накладной создается новый объект модели Самой накладной, а потом xhr запросы на сервер генерируют записи в накладной и отрисовывают на странице. Все работает, но медленно .-. На локальной машине 50-100 мс, на yandex-cloud  от 180мс до 600мс .-. Подскажите пожалуйста, как еще можно ускорить работу данного кода ?  Вот подробные детали моей реализации :

1. Models.py для накладных.

```
from Products.models import Shoe
from mainapp.models import Customer
from django.db.models import Max, Sum
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
class Naclad_sbor(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    def numbers():
        no = Naclad_sbor.objects.count()
        if no == None:
            return 1
        else:
            return no + 1
    number = models.IntegerField(_('Code'),unique=True,default=numbers)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('Созданно'),auto_now_add=True,db_index=True,)
    customer = models.CharField('Покупатель',max_length=20,blank=True,)
    number_tel = models.CharField('Номер телефона',max_length=20,blank=True,null=True,)
    Work = 'В работе'
    Sobrano = 'Собрано'
    Proverka = 'Проверка'
    Not_Oplacheno = 'Ожидает оплаты'
    Oplacheno = 'Оплаченно'
    Transp = 'Ожидает транспортировки'
    Chek = 'Проведенна'
    TYPE_CHOICES = ((Work, _('В работе')),(Sobrano, _('Собрано')),
        (Proverka, _('Проверка')),
        (Not_Oplacheno, _('Не Оплаченно')),
        (Oplacheno, _('Оплаченно')),
        (Transp, _('Ожидает транспортировки')),
        (Chek, _('Проведенна')),
    )
    type = models.CharField(
        _('Type'),
        max_length=23,
        choices=TYPE_CHOICES,
    )
    @property
    def total(self):
        return self.items.aggregate(sum=Sum('quantity_package'))['sum']
    def TotalPrise(self):
        hp = self.items.all()
        count = 0
        for tp in hp:
            gk = tp.total_prise
            count = count + gk
        return count
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created_at']
class Naclad_sbor_Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    document = models.ForeignKey(
        Naclad_sbor,
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name='items',
    )
    position = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        verbose_name=_('Position'),
        editable=False,
        db_index=True,
    )
    fason = models.CharField('Фасон', max_length=50, blank=True)
    Size = models.CharField('Размеры', max_length=50, blank=True)
    Color = models.CharField('Цвет', max_length=20, blank=True)
    vedor_code = models.CharField('Артикул', max_length=50)
    barcode = models.CharField('Штрихкод', max_length=13)
    package = models.IntegerField('Пар в упаковке', blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.IntegerField('Цена за штуку', blank=True, null=True,)
    note = models.CharField(
        max_length=50,
        blank=True,
        null=True,
    )
    sborka = models.BooleanField('Сборка', default=False)
    proverka = models.BooleanField('Проверка', default=False)
    quantity_package = models.IntegerField(
        _('Колличество упаковок'),
    )
    @property
    def total_prise(self):
        return self.price * self.package * self.quantity_package
    @property
    def mark(self):
        return round(self.price * 1.08)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.position:
            position = self.document.items.aggregate(Max('position'))['position__max'] or 0
            self.position = position + 1
        super(Naclad_sbor_Item, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['position']
```

2. Url:

```
from . import views
app_name = 'Sbor'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.sbor, name='sbor'),
    path('<int:pk>', views.naclad, name='naclad'),
    path('new_naclad', views.new_naclad, name='new_naclad'),
    path('end', views.end, name='end'),
    path('item/<int:nums>', views.item, name='item'),
    path('refresh/<int:nums>', views.refresh_data, name='refresh'),
    path('refresh_nac/<int:nums>', views.refresh_data_nac, name='refresh_nac'),
    path('add/<int:nums>', views.add, name='add'),
    path('obnov_data/<int:nums>', views.obnov_data, name='obnov'),
    path('obnov_data_nac/<int:nums>', views.obnov_data_nac, name='obnov_nac')
]
```

3. Views:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import JsonResponse
from .models import Naclad_sbor, Naclad_sbor_Item
from mainapp.models import Number, Customer
from Products.models import Shoe
@login_required
def new_naclad(request):
   Naclad_sbor.objects.create()
   tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.latest('created_at').number
   naclad_tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.get(number=tp)
   nums = str(naclad_tp.number)
   return redirect('/sbor/item/' + nums)
@login_required
def item(request, nums):
   naclad_tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.get(number=nums)
   rab = "Проведенна"
   naclads = Naclad_sbor.objects.exclude(type=rab)
   shoes = Shoe.objects.only('Color', 'vedor_code', 'Size').all()
   customers = Customer.objects.all().select_related('user')
   return render(request, 'item.html',
                 {'shoes': shoes, 'naclad_tp': naclad_tp,
                  'naclads': naclads, 'customers': customers, })
def add(request, nums):
   naclad_tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.get(number=nums)
   sbor_item = Naclad_sbor_Item()
   sbor_item.notes = request.POST.get('note')
   sbor_item.quantity_package = request.POST.get('quantity_package')
   sbor_item.document_id = naclad_tp.pk
   response = {}
   shoe = None
   if request.POST.get('shoes'):
       shoe = request.POST.get('shoes')
   if request.POST.get('barcode'):
       shoe = Shoe.objects.get(barcode=request.POST.get('barcode')).pk
   botinok = Shoe.objects.get(id=shoe)
   sbor_item.fason = botinok.fason
   sbor_item.Size = botinok.Size
   sbor_item.Color = botinok.Color
   sbor_item.vedor_code = botinok.vedor_code
   sbor_item.barcode = botinok.barcode
   sbor_item.package = botinok.package
   sbor_item.price = botinok.Prise.price
   try:
       tp = Naclad_sbor_Item.objects.get(document_id=naclad_tp.id, barcode=sbor_item.barcode)
       quant = int(sbor_item.quantity_package) + tp.quantity_package
       tp.quantity_package = quant
       tp.save()
   except Naclad_sbor_Item.DoesNotExist:
       sbor_item.save()
       pic = Shoe.objects.only('picture').get(barcode=sbor_item.barcode).picture.url
       response['fason'] = sbor_item.fason
       response['position'] = sbor_item.position
       response['Size'] = sbor_item.Size
       response['Color'] = sbor_item.Color
       response['pk'] = sbor_item.id
       response['pic'] = pic
       response['note'] = sbor_item.note
       response['shoes'] = sbor_item.vedor_code
       response['barcode'] = sbor_item.barcode
       response['quantity_package'] = sbor_item.quantity_package
       response['package'] = sbor_item.package
       response['total_prise'] = ''
       response['price'] = sbor_item.price
       response['sborka'] = sbor_item.sborka
       response['proverka'] = sbor_item.proverka
   return JsonResponse(response, content_type='application/json', safe=False)
def refresh_data(request, nums):
   # start = datetime.datetime.now()
   naclad_tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.get(number=nums)
   ti = Naclad_sbor_Item.objects.filter(document=naclad_tp.pk)
   response = []
   if request.method == 'POST':
       for item_storage in ti:
           car = item_storage.id
           item_storage.fason = request.POST.get('item_fason' + str(car))
           item_storage.Size = request.POST.get('item_Size' + str(car))
           item_storage.Color = request.POST.get('item_Color' + str(car))
           item_storage.vedor_code = request.POST.get('item_shoes' + str(car))
           item_storage.package = int(str(request.POST.get('item_package' + str(car))))
           item_storage.price = int(request.POST.get('item_price' + str(car)))
           item_storage.barcode = request.POST.get('item_barcode' + str(car))
           item_storage.quantity_package = int(request.POST.get('item_quantity_package' + str(car)))
           item_storage.note = request.POST.get('item_note' + str(car))
           if request.POST.get('sborka' + str(car)) == 'true':
               item_storage.sborka = True
           if request.POST.get('sborka' + str(car)) == 'false':
               item_storage.sborka = False
           if request.POST.get('proverka' + str(car)) == 'true':
               item_storage.proverka = True
           if request.POST.get('proverka' + str(car)) == 'false':
               item_storage.proverka = False
           item_storage.save()
           but = request.POST.get('del' + str(car))
           try:
               pic = Shoe.objects.only('picture').get(barcode=item_storage.barcode).picture.url
           except:
               pic = ''
           response.append(
               {
                   'position': item_storage.position,
                   'pk': item_storage.pk,
                   'fason': item_storage.fason,
                   'Size': item_storage.Size,
                   'Color': item_storage.Color,
                   'vedor_code': item_storage.vedor_code,
                   'package': item_storage.package,
                   'price': item_storage.price,
                   'barcode': item_storage.barcode,
                   'quantity_package': item_storage.quantity_package,
                   'note': item_storage.note,
                   'total_pr': item_storage.total_prise,
                   'del': but,
                   'proverka': item_storage.proverka,
                   'sborka': item_storage.sborka,
                   'pic': pic,
               }
           )
           if but == 'true':
               item_storage.delete()
   # end = datetime.datetime.now()
   # print(f'{end - start}')
   return JsonResponse(response, content_type='application/json', safe=False)
def obnov_data(request, nums):
   naclad_tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.get(number=nums)
   ti = Naclad_sbor_Item.objects.filter(document=naclad_tp.pk)
   response = []
   if request.method == 'GET':
       for i in ti:
           try:
               pic = Shoe.objects.only('picture').get(barcode=i.barcode).picture.url
           except:
               pic = ''
           response.append(
               {
                   'pk': i.pk,
                   'fason': i.fason,
                   'Size': i.Size,
                   'Color': i.Color,
                   'vedor_code': i.vedor_code,
                   'package': i.package,
                   'price': i.price,
                   'barcode': i.barcode,
                   'quantity_package': i.quantity_package,
                   'note': i.note,
                   'total_pr': i.total_prise,
                   'position': i.position,
                   'proverka': i.proverka,
                   'sborka': i.sborka,
                   'pic': pic,
               }
           )
   return JsonResponse(response, content_type='application/json', safe=False)
def refresh_data_nac(request, nums):
   naclad_tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.get(number=nums)
   response = {}
   if request.method == "POST":
       naclad_tp.type = request.POST.get('type')
       try:
           naclad_tp.customer = Customer.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('customer')).name
       except Customer.DoesNotExist:
           naclad_tp.customer = request.POST.get('customer')
       try:
           cust = Customer.objects.get(name=request.POST.get('customer'))
           naclad_tp.number_tel = Number.objects.get(customer=cust).number
       except:
           if request.POST.get('number_tel'):
               naclad_tp.number_tel = request.POST.get('number_tel')
           else:
               naclad_tp.number_tel = None
       naclad_tp.save()
       response['number_tel'] = naclad_tp.number_tel
   return JsonResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
def obnov_data_nac(request,nums):
   naclad_tp = Naclad_sbor.objects.get(number=nums)
   response = {}
   if request.method == "GET":
       response['type'] = naclad_tp.type
       response['customer'] = naclad_tp.customer
       response['total'] = naclad_tp.total
       response['total_pr'] = naclad_tp.TotalPrise()
       response['number_tel'] = naclad_tp.number_tel
   return JsonResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

4. Js скрипт с вьюшки:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.onload
{
    obnov();
    obnov();
}

setInterval(async function () {
    await obnov()
}, 1000*10);
async function obnov(){
    var ref = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var urls = "{% url 'Sbor:obnov_nac' naclad_tp.number %}";
    ref.open("GET", urls, true);
    ref.responseType = 'json';
    ref.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (ref.readyState === 4) {
        document.getElementById('type').value = ref.response.type;
        document.getElementById('customer').value = ref.response.customer;
        document.getElementById('total').value = ref.response.total;
        document.getElementById('total_pr').value = ref.response.total_pr;
        document.getElementById('number_tel').value = ref.response.number_tel
        }
    };
    ref.send();
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var urlq = "{% url 'Sbor:obnov' naclad_tp.number %}";
    xhr.open("GET", urlq, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            var sh = xhr.response
            let bd_item = [];
            for (let i in sh){
                let el = document.getElementById(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`);
                if (!el) {
                    var lk = document.createElement('tr')
                    lk.id = `item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`;
                    lk.innerHTML =
                        `<tr><td scope="col" style="width: 7%"><input style="padding: 0; display: inline-block; " aria-label="Позиция" class="form-control"  type="text" name="item_pos${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].position}" disabled></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Фасон" class="form-control" type="text" id="f${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_fason${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].fason}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Размер" class="form-control" type="text" id="s${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_Size${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].Size}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Цвет" class="form-control" type="text" id="c${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_Color${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].Color}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Заметка" class="form-control"  type="text" id="n${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_note${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].note}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Сборка" class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="sborka${xhr.response[i].pk}" id="sborka${xhr.response[i].pk}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Проверка" class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="proverka${xhr.response[i].pk}" id="proverka${xhr.response[i].pk}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Артикул" class="form-control" type="text" id="v${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_shoes${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].vedor_code}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td class="jop" scope="col">
                            <img src="${xhr.response[i].pic}" alt="${xhr.response[i].shoes}" class="im" width="100px" height="90px" style="display: none;"
                            onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://botinki23.ru/static/images/not-available.png'">
                            <input aria-label="Штрихкод" class="form-control" type="text" id="b${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_barcode${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].barcode}" onchange="refresh()">
                        </td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Колличество упаковок" class="form-control" type="number" id="q${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_quantity_package${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].quantity_package}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Колличество пар в упаковке" class="form-control" type="number" id="p${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_package${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].package}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Цена" class="form-control" type="number"  id="pr${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_price${xhr.response[i].pk}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].price}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Сумма" class="form-control" type="number"  id="item_total_prise${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="item_total_prise${xhr.response[i].pk}}" maxlength="50" value="${xhr.response[i].total_prise}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
                        <td scope="col"><input aria-label="Удаление" class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="del${xhr.response[i].pk}" name="del${xhr.response[i].pk}" onchange="refresh()"></td></tr>`;
                    if(!!xhr.response[i].pk){
                    document.getElementById('box_item_box').append(lk)
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if (sh.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
                    document.getElementById(`f${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].fason;
                    document.getElementById(`s${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].Size;
                    document.getElementById(`c${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].Color;
                    document.getElementById(`v${xhr.response [i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].vedor_code;
                    document.getElementById(`p${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].package;
                    document.getElementById(`pr${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].price;
                    document.getElementById(`b${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].barcode;
                    document.getElementById(`q${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].quantity_package;
                    document.getElementById(`n${xhr.response[i].pk}`).value = xhr.response[i].note;
                    document.getElementById(`item_total_prise${xhr.response[i].pk}` ).value = xhr.response[i].total_pr;
                    document.getElementById(`sborka${xhr.response[i].pk}`).checked = xhr.response[i].sborka;
                    if (xhr.response[i].sborka === true){
                        document.getElementById(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`).setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
                    }
                    document.getElementById(`proverka${xhr.response[i].pk}`).checked = xhr.response[i].proverka;
                    if (xhr.response[i].proverka === true){
                        document.getElementById(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`).setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
                    }
                    if (xhr.response[i].sborka === false & xhr.response[i].proverka === false ){
                        document.getElementById(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`).setAttribute("style", "background-color: transparent;");
                    }
                    }
                }
                bd_item.push(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`);
            }

            let elem = document.getElementById('box_item_box').children;
            let dom_item =[];
            for(var g=0, js; g<elem.length;g++){
                js = elem.item(g);
                dom_item.push(js.id);
            }
            var c = dom_item.filter(n => bd_item.indexOf(n) === -1);
            for (let q of c){
                document.getElementById(q).remove();
            }
        }
    };
    xhr.send();

    $(function () {
    $('.jop').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.im').show();
  },function(){
    $(this).find('.im').hide();
  });
  })
}

async function refresh_nac(){
    let naclads = 'nuc_num=' + {{naclad_tp.number}} + '&' +
        'type=' + document.getElementById('type').value + '&' +
        'customer=' + document.getElementById('customer').value + '&' +
        'number_tel=' + document.getElementById('number_tel').value + '&' +
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ csrf_token }}';
    let response = await fetch("{% url 'Sbor:refresh_nac' naclad_tp.number %}", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        },
        body: naclads
});
}

async function add(){
    let addreq = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let url = "{% url 'Sbor:add' naclad_tp.number %}";
    let data = `shoes=${document.getElementById('id_shoes').value}&quantity_package=${document.getElementById('id_quantity_package').value}&barcode=${document.getElementById('bar').value}&note=${document.getElementById('id_note').value}&csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ csrf_token }}`;
    addreq.open('POST', url, true);
    addreq.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    addreq.responseType = 'json';
    addreq.onreadystatechange = function (){
        if (addreq.readyState === 4) {
            var tr = document.createElement('tr')
            tr.id = 'item_box' + addreq.response.pk;
            tr.innerHTML =
            `<td><input style="padding: 0; display: inline-block;" aria-label="Позиция" class="form-control"  type="text" name="item_pos${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.position}" disabled></td>
            <td><input aria-label="Фасон" class="form-control" type="text" id="f${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_fason${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.fason}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
            <td><input aria-label="Размер" class="form-control" type="text" id="s${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_Size${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.Size}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
            <td><input aria-label="Цвет" class="form-control" type="text" id="c${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_Color${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.Color}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
            <td><input aria-label="Заметка" class="form-control"  type="text" id="n${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_note${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.note}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td><input  aria-label="Сборка" class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="sborka${addreq.response.pk}" id="sborka${addreq.response.pk}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td><input aria-label="Проверка" class="form-control" type="checkbox" name="proverka${addreq.response.pk}" id="proverka${addreq.response.pk}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td><input aria-label="Артикул" class="form-control" type="text" id="v${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_shoes${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.shoes}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td class="jop">
            <img src="${addreq.response.pic}" alt="${addreq.response.shoes}" class="im" width="100px" height="90px" style="display: none;"
            onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='http://botinki23.ru/static/images/not-available.png'">
             <input aria-label="Штрихкод" class="form-control" type="text" id="b${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_barcode${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.barcode}" onchange="refresh()">
          </td>
          <td><input aria-label="Колличество упаковок" class="form-control" type="number" id="q${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_quantity_package${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.quantity_package}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td><input aria-label="Колличество пар в упаковке" class="form-control" type="number" id="p${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_package${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.package}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td><input aria-label="Цена" class="form-control" type="number"  id="pr${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_price${addreq.response.pk}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.price}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td><input aria-label="Сумма" class="form-control" type="number"  id="item_total_prise${addreq.response.pk}" name="item_total_prise${addreq.response.pk}}" maxlength="50" value="${addreq.response.total_prise}" onchange="refresh()"></td>
          <td><input aria-label="Удаление" class="form-control" type="checkbox" id="del${addreq.response.pk}" name="del${addreq.response.pk}" onchange="refresh()"></td>`;
            if(!!addreq.response.pk){
                document.getElementById('box_item_box').append(tr)
            }
            document.getElementById('bar').value = '';
            document.getElementById('id_shoes').value = '';
            document.getElementById('bar').focus();
        }

    };
    addreq.send(data);
}

async function refresh(){
    let lol = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let urlq = "{% url 'Sbor:obnov' naclad_tp.number %}";
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let urlg = "{% url 'Sbor:refresh' naclad_tp.number %}";
    let shoe = '';
    lol.open("GET", urlq, true);
    lol.responseType = 'json';
    lol.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (lol.readyState === 4) {
        var sh = lol.response
        for (let i in sh){
            shoe = shoe +
                'item_fason' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('f' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_Size' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('s' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_Color' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('c' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_shoes' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('v' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_package' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('p' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_price' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('pr' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_barcode' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('b' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_quantity_package' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('q' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'item_note' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('n' + lol.response[i].pk).value + '&' +
                'del' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('del' + lol.response[i].pk).checked + '&' +
                'proverka' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('proverka' + lol.response[i].pk).checked + '&' +
                'sborka' + lol.response[i].pk + '=' + document.getElementById('sborka' + lol.response[i].pk).checked + '&';
            }
        shoe = shoe + 'csrfmiddlewaretoken={{ csrf_token }}';
        xhr.open("POST", urlg, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhr.responseType = 'json';
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (lol.readyState === 4) {
                let sh = xhr.response;
                for (let i in sh){
                    if(xhr.response[i].del === 'true'){
                        document.getElementById('item_box'+ xhr.response[i].pk).remove()
                    }
                    document.getElementById(`sborka${xhr.response[i].pk}`).checked = xhr.response[i].sborka;
                    if (xhr.response[i].sborka === true){
                        document.getElementById(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`).setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");}document.getElementById(`proverka${xhr.response[i].pk}`).checked = xhr.response[i].proverka;
                    if (xhr.response[i].proverka === true){     document.getElementById(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`).setAttribute("style", "background-color: green;");
                    }
                    if (xhr.response[i].sborka === false & xhr.response[i].proverka === false ){
                        document.getElementById(`item_box${xhr.response[i].pk}`).setAttribute("style", "background-color: transparent;");
                    }
        }
            }
        }
        xhr.send(shoe)
    }
    };
    lol.send();
}
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Думаю вьюшки самого редактирования накладной хватит.

Comment: Подключите https://github.com/jazzband/django-debug-toolbar и выполните медленные запросы, он вам покажет, где на серверной стороне тратится время. Еще нужно посмотреть профиль выполнения запроса/ов в браузере (в хроме это в закладке network). Не зная, где тратится время, сложно что-то подсказать. Кроме того, нужно в вопросе указывать, какая именно операция медленная и что именно вы измеряете. Это можно делать очень по разному

Comment: Я уже уже сделал это больше всего времени уходит на TTFB toolbar, показывает что большая часть времени работы уходит на CPUtime, и ProcessorTime. Все что мне об это сказало что сервер тормозит и его надо ускорить .-. Поэтому решил не указывать это в вопросе.

Comment: Повторюсь. Нужно четко указать 1. какой запрос тормозит 2. что именно меряете Далее cputime - это ничего не дает. Чтоб улучшить производительность нужно искать что именно долго выполнялось, какой именно код. Нужен результат профилирования (включая `django-debug-toolbar-line-profiler`).